# How do I get my colleague to send me the requested data?

Tags: conflict, conflict-resolution, escalation

I need certain test data in order to make improvements to our product. My colleague reported the issue but over the last month has ignored my repeated requests for data, while continuously reiterating the failure (without any metrics) and asking for a fix. We need this fix if it is indeed an issue.

At this point, what do I do? Escalate? Ask again? This would be the 5th time. Both?

Comment: How have you asked them? If the issue is important, I would call them and explain why a MRE is needed and how it should be provided. If it isn't important, I would close the issue with a comment that it can be reopened when test data is provided.

Comment: Did you ask your co-worker via emails ? Try email again, but also pick up the phone and call him/her directly and leave a message on the phone if possible. If this is truly a critical issue, then perhaps you should gently escalate it by asking your manager on how to get your co-worker to send the data. You could also CC the request to your co-worker's manager.

Comment: @Roland What is MRE? What is an "issue"?

Comment: Forward your requests, and his replies to his boss copied to yours as well. If it needs fixing then that will get it done.

Comment: Just a comment, you should absolutely make sure you are indeed blocked on the lack of information. If this gets escalated, you don't want to look like an idiot.

Comment: Escalate to your Manager for guidance but one approach is - the first 2 or 3 emails just to them after that you start copying in people higher and higher up the chain (their boss, their bosses boss etc etc).

Answer (score 4):

If you (your organization / team) is using a tracking / ticketing system (ex: Jira), please move the corresponding task to blocked (or equivalent) state, leaving a comment asking about specific data that you'd need to reproduce the issue. This way, the onus will be back to the original reporter, not on you.

If, for some reason, you have an offline tracking mechanism for bugs, you need to do couple of things:

1. Push (to your level best) for a centralized tracking system to be in place.
2. Try to meet them in-person / over phone/teams call and explain why you need the data and how you are blocked acting upon the issue raised by them due to lack of data.
3. Reply on email, with your and their boss in CC, and mention the need of the data AND also mention that you'll only be able to progress AFTER you get the requested input from their side.

Answer (score 3):

Reach out to you colleague, organize a meeting (either in person or via video call) and have them show you the issue, by replicating it for you. Then try to understand why that is an issue for them.

If the above doesn't happen because your colleague doesn't cooperate, then you can pull both managers in the loop, communicating that you have received the reported issue but lack data (specify what data) to fix it. State that you have arranged the meeting to get those data but that did not work, and that the issue will be on hold until your colleague provides the needed data.